Sort by 4th and 2nd columns
I got the below code from google for retrieving last 10 records- I am trying to sort the resulting range alone which will be displayed in html form. Problem is the below sorting order sorts on my 4th column, but I also want to sort next by 2nd column. - How to achieve that?
const SPREADSHEETID = "<<sheetid>>";
const DATARANGE = "Data!A2:F";
const DATASHEET = "Data";

function readRecord(range) {
  try {
    let result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SPREADSHEETID, range); 
    return result.values;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

function getLastTenRecords() {
  let lastRow = readRecord(DATARANGE).length + 1;
  let startRow = lastRow - 20;
  if (startRow < 2) { 
    startRow = 2;
  }
  let range = DATASHEET + "!A" + startRow + ":" + LASTCOL + lastRow;
  let lastTenRecords = readRecord(range);
  Logger.log(lastTenRecords);
  return lastTenRecords.sort((a, b) => a[4] > b[4] ? 4 : -4);
}


Use Array.slice() and two instances of Array.sort(), like this:
function getLastTenRecords() {
  const data = readRecord(DATARANGE);
  return data.slice(data.length - 10)
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
    .sort((a, b) => a[3] - b[3]);
}

Apps Script is JavaScript V8 and has stable sorting since 2019. This feature lets you first sort by one key and then by another, maintaining the relative order of rows that have the same value in a sort key. The primary sort key should come last in the method chain.
JavaScript arrays use zero-based indexing, so the fourth column has index 3 and the second column has index 1.
In the event those columns aren't numeric but contain text strings that must be sorted lexicographically, use a closure in .sort(), like this:
function getLastTenRecords() {
  const data = readRecord(DATARANGE);
  const _compare = i => (a, b) =>
    a[i] < b[i]
      ? -1
      : a[i] > b[i]
        ? 1
        : 0;
  return data.slice(data.length - 10)
    .sort(_compare(1))
    .sort(_compare(3));
}

See Array.slice() and Array.sort().

perfect solution !! thank you so much @doubleunary !!
